# LinqToTwitter Authorization Help

Tags: authorization

I am using LinqToTwitter (http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), but
I haven't a clue about where to start with the authorization thing. So far I have this:

```
var oAuth = new OAuthTwitter ();
oAuth.OAuthConsumerKey ="mykey";
oAuth.OAuthConsumerSecret ="mySecret" ;

string loginUrl = oAuth.AuthorizationLinkGet( 
   "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" , 
   "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize", "", true ); 
var twitterCtx = new TwitterContext ();

//return Redirect(loginUrl); //(ASP.NET) 

var publicTweets = from tweet in twitterCtx.Status 
where tweet.Type == StatusType .Public 
select tweet; publicTweets.ToList().ForEach(tweet => AddItem(tweet.User.Name, tweet.Text));
```

I just want the quickest, simplest way of authorizing the desktop app. I couldn't find much documentation.

FYI - This won't be for multiple users... I will have a single user name and password that will always be used... if that helps make it simpler.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example:

```
var auth = new SingleUserAuthorizer
{
    Credentials = new InMemoryCredentials
    {
        ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerKey"],
        ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterConsumerSecret"],
        OAuthToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAccessToken"],
        AccessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TwitterAccessTokenSecret"]
    }
};

using (var db = new TwitterContext(auth))
{
    string search = Server.UrlEncode(txtSearch.Text.Trim());

    var list = db.User
              .Where(u =>
                        u.Type == UserType.Search &&
                        u.Query == searchExpression &&
                        u.Page == 1
                        )
              .ToList();  
}
```