# LinqToTwitter authentication MVC 4 examples

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-twitter

I've downloaded LinqToTwitter (v3.0.2) and added it to my asp.net MVC 4 project. I've previously been working with version 2.1.3 of LinqToTwitter and webforms. I'm now looking for some examples to guide me in the right direction when it comes to authentication and the use of LinqToTwitter 3.0.2 (now the latest).

I've done a bit of googling but havn't found any good examples that illustrates the whole flow.

Any of you guys have links to examples?

Thanx!

Comment: have you ever see this post: [LinqToTwitter Authorization Help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7020650/linqtotwitter-authorization-help)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version of LINQ to Twitter is async. You can find samples in the downloadable source code in the [Linq2TwitterDemos_MVC](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Linq2TwitterDemos_MVC/Controllers/OAuthController.cs) project. The [Documentation](http://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/documentation) has both old and new versions of queries.